# Use an element's variable width with CSS calc

Tags: html, css, sass, less

How can I use CSS calc() or a preprocessor to center an absolutely positioned element horizontally, regardless of the element's width? Something to the effect of:

```
.elem {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: calc(-.5 * elem.width);
}
```

I want to keep a class of absolutely positioned elements, whose widths are dynamic, centered horizontally relative to their parent divs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To horizontally center an absolutely positioned element with `left:50%;` Use `translateX`.

```
.elem {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /*To align Vertically and Horizontally
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  */
}
```